# How to know if the Gtk::ComboBoxText is popup

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I am writing a simple GUI, in which I have a ComboBoxText. I write a log message when ever the user clicks on the ComboBoxText. 
I have tried almost all the button release and popup signals but no results. The only thing which works is signal_changed() but I don't not need that. Please help me, below is my sample code :

```
myCombo->signal_button_release_event().connect(sigc::mem_fun(this,&ComboBoxText::ComboInput),false);
```

and here is the call back function:

```
bool ComboBoxText::ComboInput(GdkEventButton *pEvt) { 

// Here do the desired stuffs !! 
return false; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GTK+ property `popup-shown`. Not sure about Gtkmm syntax, probably `property_popup_shown().get_value()`.

If you need a signal to listen to, connect to `popdown` or `notify::popup-shown` (the latter is invoked when property value changes; again, I'm not sure about Gtkmm syntax).

Comment: Thank you so much but this is not what I am looking for. I need a similar mechanism as in the Button click event. I need to have a signal handler and which should get called when ever someone clicks the ComboBoxText.

Answer (score 0):

The idea here was to fire an event when the ComboBoxText is clicked. After some readings I figured it out that the ComboBoxText does not fire any on_click event as such. 
One could mask a key press event (which by the way gets fired) and call the signal handler. This might not be handy for people who specifically looking for a on_click event but for those who are working with a keyboard or touch screen device. Here is a small chunk of code :`

mCombo.add_events(Gdk::KEY_PRESS_MASK);
                 mCombo.signal_event().connect(sigc::mem_fun(this,&ClassName::Handler),false);

cheers :)